# Get the sales count within a month

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have monthly agents' sales data. I need to get the first 25 days sales count and last 5 days columns.
How to get in separately.

I have below table

```
Agent_ID       Date         Device
2343          1/1/2019       33330
3245          1/1/2019       43554
2343          5/1/2019       46665
3245          10/1/2019      78900
2343          15/1/2019      55678
2343          26/1/2019      45678
3245          28/1/2019      48900
2343          30/1/2019      56710
5645          12/1/2019      33067
5645          15/1/2019      44890
2121          31/1/2019      55810
```

I need to get this below output table

```
Agent_ID   first_25days_sale_count     Last_5days_sale_count
2343                 3                          2
3245                 2                          1
5645                 2                          0
2121                 0                          1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some months have 28, 29 or 31 days so naively using "first 25 days" and "last 5 days" may lead to either double counting (i.e. days 24 and 25 when February has 28 days) or not counting some days (i.e. day 26 when the the month has 31 days). You should decide whether you want to count:

- The first 25 days and then the remaining 3-6 days after that; or
- The last 5 days and then the 23-26 days before that.

Whichever you chose, you can use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT agent_id,
       COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN EXTRACT( DAY FROM "Date" ) <= 25
         THEN 1
         END
       ) AS first_25days_sale_count,
       COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN EXTRACT( DAY FROM "Date" ) > 25
         THEN 1
         END
       ) AS after_first_25days_sale_count,
       COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN "Date" < TRUNC( LAST_DAY( "Date" ) ) - INTERVAL '4' DAY
         THEN 1
         END
       ) AS not_last_5days_sale_count,
       COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN "Date" >= TRUNC( LAST_DAY( "Date" ) ) - INTERVAL '4' DAY
         THEN 1
         END
       ) AS last_5days_sale_count
FROM   your_table
GROUP BY agent_id;
```

So, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table ( Agent_ID, "Date", Device ) AS
SELECT 2343, DATE '2019-01-01', 33330 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3245, DATE '2019-01-01', 43554 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2343, DATE '2019-01-05', 46665 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3245, DATE '2019-01-10', 78900 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2343, DATE '2019-01-15', 55678 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2343, DATE '2019-01-26', 45678 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3245, DATE '2019-01-29', 48900 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2343, DATE '2019-01-30', 56710 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5645, DATE '2019-01-12', 33067 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5645, DATE '2019-01-15', 44890 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2121, DATE '2019-01-31', 55810 FROM DUAL;
```

This outputs:

> ```
> AGENT_ID | FIRST_25DAYS_SALE_COUNT | AFTER_FIRST_25DAYS_SALE_COUNT | NOT_LAST_5DAYS_SALE_COUNT | LAST_5DAYS_SALE_COUNT
> -------: | ----------------------: | ----------------------------: | ------------------------: | --------------------:
>     3245 |                       2 |                             1 |                         2 |                     1
>     2121 |                       0 |                             1 |                         0 |                     1
>     5645 |                       2 |                             0 |                         2 |                     0
>     2343 |                       3 |                             2 |                         4 |                     1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fc800756ea1e1fdbfc1841fe008af05f)*

Comment: how to filter LAST_5DAYS_SALE_COUNT > NOT_LAST_5DAYS_SALE_COUNT ?       I tried 'HAVING" function it not working

Comment: @ShulazShan Don't use the column aliases; use the full aggregations: `HAVING COUNT( CASE ... END ) > COUNT( CASE ... END )`. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a749eba2b74f815885d6a584564b0a23)

Comment: can u plz tell if I want to filter who did more sale at the end of the month continuously 3 months from the system month(eg: if it September as system month, then consider Aug, July, June who did more sale in the end of that past 3 months)

Comment: @ShulazShan That is outside the scope of this question. You should ask a new question and include a [MRE] with some sample data, your expected results and your attempt at the answer and what is wrong with it.